# how to catch a out of memory Exception in AsyncTask

Tags: java, android, http

My android application connect do an external database using a Web Service. In one case I have **Enormous** number of data, and I got **out of memory exception**:

```
09-09 20:05:59.441: ERROR/dalvikvm(4688): Out of memory: Heap Size=15751KB, Allocated=14962KB, Bitmap Size=687KB
09-09 20:05:59.451: WARN/dalvikvm(4688): threadid=23: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001e390)
09-09 20:05:59.462: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4688): Uncaught handler: thread AsyncTask #5 exiting due to uncaught exception
09-09 20:05:59.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4688): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
09-09 20:05:59.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4688):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
09-09 20:05:59.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4688):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
09-09 20:05:59.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4688):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
09-09 20:05:59.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4688):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
09-09 20:05:59.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4688):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
09-09 20:05:59.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4688):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1068)
09-09 20:05:59.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4688):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:561)
09-09 20:05:59.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4688):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1102)
09-09 20:05:59.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4688): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
09-09 20:05:59.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4688):     at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.enlargeBuffer(AbstractStringBuilder.java:97)
09-09 20:05:59.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4688):     at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append0(AbstractStringBuilder.java:142)
09-09 20:05:59.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4688):     at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:124)
09-09 20:05:59.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4688):     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextString(JSONTokener.java:252)
09-09 20:05:59.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4688):     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:316)
09-09 20:05:59.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4688):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:204)
09-09 20:05:59.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4688):     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:319)
09-09 20:05:59.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4688):     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:204)
09-09 20:05:59.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4688):     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:319)
09-09 20:05:59.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4688):     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:116)
09-09 20:05:59.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4688):     at org.json.JSONArray.<init>(JSONArray.java:150)
09-09 20:05:59.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4688):     at se.softwerk.timelog.activity.ViewActivity.setTasks(ViewActivity.java:219)
09-09 20:05:59.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4688):     at se.softwerk.timelog.activity.ViewActivity.fetchTasks(ViewActivity.java:133)
09-09 20:05:59.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4688):     at se.softwerk.timelog.activity.ViewActivity.access$9(ViewActivity.java:110)
09-09 20:05:59.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4688):     at se.softwerk.timelog.activity.ViewActivity$LoadingDataFromServer.doInBackground(ViewActivity.java:420)
09-09 20:05:59.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4688):     at se.softwerk.timelog.activity.ViewActivity$LoadingDataFromServer.doInBackground(ViewActivity.java:1)
09-09 20:05:59.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4688):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
09-09 20:05:59.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4688):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
09-09 20:05:59.731: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4688):     ... 4 more
```

This is my class:

```
private class LoadingDataFromServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        public void onPreExecute() {
            progress = ProgressDialog.show(ViewActivity.this, null,"Loading ...", true);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            try {
                ListView lv = (ListView) main_activity.findViewById(R.id.listTask);
                lv.setAdapter(new TaskAdapter(main_activity));
                progress.dismiss();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                fetchTasks();
            } catch (Exception e) {      //DOES NOT WORK
                progress.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(ViewActivity.this, "Enormous number of data, select smaller criteria", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

How can I catch this Exception in `doInBackground`?
My current trying does not work.

Comment: catching trowable is one thing but you can avoid this error using one of the pull parser fx jackson

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679330/catching-java-lang-outofmemoryerror

Answer (score 6):

[OutOfmemoryError](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html) doesn't extends Exception, this is why you don't catch it.

This code should work.

```
try
{
    fetchTasks();       
}
catch(OutOfMemoryError e)
{
    // do something     
}
```

Comment: Or alternatively one can catch ``Throwable``. Yet I wonder is this a proper way for handling this error situation.

Answer (score 3):

```
try {
    ...
} catch (Exception e) {  // "catch all subclasses of java.lang.Exception"
    ...
}
```

However, `OutOfMemoryError` inherits from `java.lang.Error` and not `java.lang.Exception` and they both inherit from `java.lang.Throwable`. You can only `throw` instances of subclasses of `java.lang.Throwable` in java so you can catch **any** error or exception with this:

```
try {
    ...
} catch (Throwable t) {  // "catch all subclasses of java.lang.Throwable"
    ...
}
```

Comment: good to know, but it was not my error. check my answer please, if you have any idea, I appreciate to can hear that.