# Why does Java allow catching Error types when applications aren't supposed to handle them?

Tags: java, exception, out-of-memory

In Java, the following  is allowed:

```
public void handleError() {
    try {
        System.out.println("Out of memory error!!");
    } catch(OutOfMemoryError outOfMemoryError) {
        System.out.println(
            "This is catch block of out of memory error Message:"+
            outOfMemoryError.getMessage());
    }
}
```

In what situation is the above code valid? If the app runs out of memory then will the app even execute, and why is the above code valid?

Comment: "not recommended" != "not allowed"

Comment: @WilliamPrice In what situation is the above error handeling appropriate?

Comment: It's allowed anywhere you write it, and "appropriate" if you think you can do something to relieve the memory pressure.  In an OOM situation, however, it's questionable whether the system will be able to complete the `catch` block; it depends on what's involved.  It also doesn't guarantee that your program won't continue to encounter OOM issues after the error is handled.  **But you can try.**  It's _not recommended_ to catch errors because they're usually created in situations where it's hard to guarantee specific behavior/outcomes.

Comment: The documentation uses the phrases "reasonable application" and "most applications".

Answer (score 2):

The OutOfMemoryError exception is thrown when you don't have enough memory on your heap to create a specific object. So if you were trying to create a massive object that required the maximum amount of space your heap had, you would get the error. That doesn't necessarily mean that there is no memory available though. You could still have enough memory to create the exception object, and run the code in the catch block.

Answer (score 1):

1.) Some massive data structures are there that is not used anymore, and can set to null and free up some memory.

2.) catch an `OutOfMemoryError` and that is to close down `gracefully`, cleanly releasing resources and logging the reason for the failure best you can.

detailed explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679330/catching-java-lang-outofmemoryerror) and [here](https://plumbr.eu/blog/understanding-java-lang-outofmemoryerror)

Answer (score 1):

The answer by [Chris Bregg](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25986750/why-does-java-allow-catching-error-types-when-applications-arent-supposed-to-ha/25986815#25986815) provides correct information, that  `OutOfMemoryError` is thrown when you ask for some memory to get allocated but JVM doesn't have that much memory available thus it throws `OutOfMemoryError`.
Moreover the `OutOfMemoryError` occurs due to request of **block memory allocation** by application that cannot be fulfilled with the remaining memory in the heap.

The only one thing that comes in my mind, where it can come handy is when you want to close the application gracefully while logging the information (that can come handy when such thing occurs at client side and helps the developer to get the information to fix such issues) and releasing all the resources nicely.

**EDIT**

A small example to demonstrate `OutOfMemoryError` exception due to request by app asking for the block of memory that can be satisfied due to heap size,

```
package deepakTest;

public class App 
{   
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        int arrySize = Integer.MAX_VALUE;        
        int[] intArray;
        while (true) 
        {
            try 
            {
                intArray = new int[arrySize];
                break;
            }
            catch (OutOfMemoryError e) 
            {
                System.out.println("OutOfMemoryError while trying to allocate the array with size " + arrySize);
                arrySize--;
            }
        }

        System.out.println("Sucessfully allocated the array with size " + arrySize);
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is the case then why does most of the blogs and all that claim that error shouldnot be handeled?

Comment: @Smrita as it is mentioned that this error should not be handled is because if you handle it then also your program can not continue further and if it survives few further lines of code then too probability of next `OutOfMemoryError` is very high until and unless big chunks of memory have been released.

Comment: @Smrita: Code should only handle such conditions if they are prepared to deal with the complications associated with them.  In most cases, proper handling of all the complications is more trouble than its worth, and code which isn't prepared to do that shouldn't try to handle such conditions.  In some cases, however, the value in handling such conditions may be worth the effort required to do it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The code is valid, because as far as the syntax and language rules go, it's correct.
However this doesn't mean that there will be a specific use case for the same.

Comment: And my question is if there's no use case then why allow the syntax to be valid?