# Java Heap size issue

Tags: java, multithreading, memory-management, jvm, out-of-memory

**Preface:-** I have a export functionality in my application, which gives me the output in excel.
The application in which i am working is a very restricted application in a sense that you can't do much by your self and you have to rely on the application architecture.

**Problem Statement:-** There are certian scenarios in which my application exports around 2 lacs records from the database.
I make query and i pass it on to a framework, which in itself executes it and pass me a list carrying result.I cannot excess the framework.
Sometimes when the result size is too much,for example 2lacs, the application throws java heap size error.

**Question:-** My question is how can i check if my heap size is crashing and before JVM throws error, i should be able to check and stop it's execution and throw an customized message to the user.
Can i start a thread for that?

Comment: one thing which i forgot in the question is that i cannot increase the heap size as it is already 3GB and its further increase cost is high.

Comment: Related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679330/catching-java-lang-outofmemoryerror

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh  100.000

Comment: Try to not produce the whole Excel file in memory (and certainly don't load the whole result set into memory all at once). There must be a way to stream both.