# Is there a way to catch OutOfMemory error in AWS Lambda function (written in Java)?

Tags: java, exception, aws-lambda

Is there a way to catch OutOfMemory error in AWS Lambda function (written in Java)?

The error is thrown by the 'main' method thread which I think is not exposed.

Comment: Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679330/catching-java-lang-outofmemoryerror

Comment: @lexicore: I understand that. The question is specific to AWS Lambda functions where the OutOfMemory error is thrown in 'main' thread that is not exposed to the user. Only the function handler is exposed.

Comment: You'll probably need to post some code. Which "main thread"? What is a "function handler"?