# "OutOfMemoryError" when onClick gets called (Crash report)

Tags: java, onclick, crash, out-of-memory, developer-console

My App gets a lot of crash reports

The App crashes when the onClickListener gets called.
Only Android Version 7.0 and 7.1 are affected.
I already tried to launch the App on a Emulator with Android Version 7 but on the Emulator everything works fine.

This is the crash report:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError:
  at dalvik.system.VMRuntime.newNonMovableArray (Native Method)
  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset (Native Method)
  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream (BitmapFactory.java:655)
  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream             (BitmapFactory.java:483)
  at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream (Drawable.java:1157)
  at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawableForCookie (ResourcesImpl.java:720)
  at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadDrawable (ResourcesImpl.java:571)
  at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable (Resources.java:889)
  at android.content.Context.getDrawable (Context.java:530)
  at android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat.getDrawable (ContextCompat.java:351)
  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable (AppCompatDrawableManager.java:200)
  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatDrawableManager.getDrawable (AppCompatDrawableManager.java:188)
  at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable (AppCompatResources.java:100)
  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.setImageResource (AppCompatImageHelper.java:85)
  at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView.setImageResource (AppCompatImageView.java:94)
  at com.future.king.johncena.tabs.Tab1$1.onClick (Tab1.java:94)
  at android.view.View.performClick (View.java:5675)
  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run (View.java:22641)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:836)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:103)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:203)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6251)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:1063)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:924)
```

and this is my onClickListener:

```
public void button() {
  button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
      cleanUpMediaPlayer();
      mp = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.sound);

      mp.start();
      if(!sound1){
        mp.setVolume(0.0f, 0.0f);
      }

      button.setImageResource(R.drawable.button1);
      mp.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
          button.setImageResource(R.drawable.button);
        }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Line 94 is

```
button.setImageResource(R.drawable.button1);
```

I hope someone can tell me what's causing this crash.

Comment: How big is the image? Do you get the same if you try to call `setImageResource` outside of an onClickListener?

Comment: @S.L.Barth The image is 512x512. The problem is that on my Emulator with Android version 7 everything works fine, that means I have to upload it, and wait till users send the crash reports.

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend using `selector` state drawables for the `button` and change the button state rather than setting image resources in `onClick` method.

See [State List documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#StateList) for reference.

Comment: Okay thank you, do you have any idea how I can test it? Instead of updating the app and waiting for user crash reports?

Comment: I have a theory that this OOM is a result of a button spam click, since you're not preventing it in the code. Try to spam it repeatedly, this might be the cause. Either way, set button `setClickable(false);` when user first clicks it and make it clickable again after the sound has been played.

Comment: Yes that may cause the crash. Is is possible that I put everything in the onClick Method in a Try and Catch? 
So the app dont crash?

Comment: `try { } catch { }` is not a solution to the problem. Overrall, catching OOMException is not a good idea ([Refer this question for further explanations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679330/catching-java-lang-outofmemoryerror/2680784))

Comment: The thing is that the user should be allowed to spam the button.

Comment: Onclick execution should atleast be blocked before last invoke is finished. Furthermore, try using some library like `Glide` to set image resources.

Comment: How do I block it?

Comment: Invoke `button.setClickable(false)` In your listener, then, when Media player oncompletion is invoked, make it clickable again