# Drop part of a List<> when encountering OutOfMemoryException

Tags: java

I'm writing a program that is supposed to continually push generated data into a List sensorQueue. The side effect is that I will eventually run out of memory. When that happens, I'd like drop parts of the list, in this example the first, or older, half. I imagine that if I encounter an `OutOfMemeryException`, I won't be able to just use `sensorQueue = sensorQueue.subList((sensorQueue.size() / 2), sensorQueue.size());`, so I came here looking for an answer.

My code:

```
public static void pushSensorData(String sensorData) {
    try {
        sensorQueue.add(parsePacket(sensorData));
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
        System.out.println("Backlog full");

        //TODO: Cut the sensorQueue in half to make room
    }
    System.out.println(sensorQueue.size());
}
```

Comment: Why do you keep the values in the `sensorQueue` list and not remove the items when you have done your work with the entries?

Comment: Even trimming down an existing list would require new allocations, so if you are already out of memory you have no guarantee that this would succeed either

Comment: @Progman The assignment requires to keep all generated data at hand and willfully accepts that the program will run out of memory eventually. I however would like my program to not just crash eventually.

Comment: @UnholySheep Is there an easy way to detect an impending OutOfMemoryException then? Or any other way that would allow me to keep my program running?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Catching java.lang.OutOfMemoryError?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679330/catching-java-lang-outofmemoryerror)

Comment: I'd recommend using `removeRange(from, to)`. It doesn't create another list (modifies current one instead) so will not require additional memory.

Comment: @Ziumin If you feel confident in your suggested solution, could you write a proper answer? Your suggestion would require me to write a custom list that extends List, no?

Comment: Best would be to just stop the program, maybe to try some cleanup before stopping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an easy way to detect an impending OutOfMemoryException then?

You can have something like below to determine MAX memory and USED memory. Using that information you can define next set of actions in your programme. e.g. reduce its size or drop some elements.

```
final int MEGABYTE = (1024*1024);
MemoryMXBean memoryBean = ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean();
MemoryUsage heapUsage = memoryBean.getHeapMemoryUsage();
long maxMemory = heapUsage.getMax() / MEGABYTE;
long usedMemory = heapUsage.getUsed() / MEGABYTE;
```

Hope this would helps!

Answer (score 1):

The problem with `subList` is that it creates sublist keeping the original one in memory. However, `ArrayList` or other extension of [AbstractList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractList.html) has `removeRange(int fromIndex, int toIndex)` which removes elements of current list, so doesn't require additional memory.

For the other [List](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html) implementations there is similar `remove(int index)` which you can use multiple times for the same purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I think you idea is severely flawed (sorry).

There is no OutOfMemoryException, there is OutOfMemory**Error** only! Why that is important? Because errors leaves app in unstable state, well I'm not that sure about that claim in general, but it definitely holds for OutOfMemoryError. Because there is no guarantee, that you will be able to catch it! You can consume all of memory within you try-catch block, and OutOfMemoryError will be thrown somewhere in JDK code. So your catching is pointless.

And what is the reason for this anyways? How many messages do you want in list? Say that your message is 1MB. And your heap is 1000MB. So if we stop considering other classes, your heap size define, that your list will contain up to 1000 messages, right? Wouldn't it be easier to set heap sufficiently big for your desired number of messages, and specify message count in easier, intergral form? And if your answer is "no", then you still cannot catch OutOfMemoryError reliably, so I'd advise that your answer rather should be "yes".

If you really need to consume all what is possible, then checking memory usage in % as @fabsas recommended could be way. But I'd go with integral definition — easier to managed. Your list will contain up-to N messages.

Comment: + you really want to use proper list implementation for easy trimming of leading items, see some benchmarsk, but maybe https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/list/TreeList.html could be good choice.

Answer (score -1):

You can drop a range of elements from a `ArrayList` using [`subList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#subList-int-int-):

```
list.subList(from, to).clear();
```

Where `from` is the first index of the range to be removed and `to` is the last. In your case, you can do something like:

```
list.subList(0, sensorQueue.size() / 2).clear();
```

Note that this command will return a List.

Comment: The page you linked to states: *"The returned list is backed by this list"* - which means that the original list is still kept in memory (and contradicts your claim that it removes from the list)

Comment: I'm pretty sure the sublist is GC'ed and the list is reduced. I just ran a small test. The clear will have effect on the backed list.

Comment: @UnholySheep This method is mentioned in Oracle's official Java Tutorial at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html under "Range-View Operation" saying that "This method eliminates the need for explicit range operations".

Comment: Either way, both in the Javadoc (the link in the answer) and in the tutorial, this method is specifically mentioned. As it is a range view I'm quessing it doesn't require a lot of memory either.