# can programatic creation of android artifacts (relativelayout, button etc) fail in Kotlin/Java due to OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android, kotlin, memory, jvm

When I create a RelativeLayout(or a Button, textview etc) in Android programmatically:

```
val rl: RelativeLayout = RelativeLayout (this)
```

Now, can there be a scenario when the OS is not able to allocate any memory to create the RelativeLayout? If yes then How to handle it?

In the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout#RelativeLayout(android.content.Context)), it is not mentioned anywhere if it will return null in this scenario (which I think it won't as rl is non-nullable and the above code doesn't give any compilation error) or if it will give an OutOfMemoryError exception and I have to use a try-catch to handle it.

Is this behavior documented anywhere?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it may occur. try using ErrorCatch Exception.

```
    try {
        val rl: RelativeLayout = RelativeLayout(this)

    } catch (e: OutOfMemoryError) {
        println(e.toString)
    }
```

Comment: Is this behavior documented anywhere? that It will give an OutOfMemoryError exception error

Comment: You [need to be very careful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679330/catching-java-lang-outofmemoryerror) about catching `OutOfMemoryError`.