# Can the JVM recover from an OutOfMemoryError without a restart

Tags: java, jvm, out-of-memory

1. Can the JVM recover from an `OutOfMemoryError` without a restart if it gets a chance to run the GC before more object allocation requests come in?
2. Do the various JVM implementations differ in this aspect?

My question is about the JVM recovering and not the user program trying to recover by catching the error. In other words if an OOME is thrown in an application server (jboss/websphere/..) do I **have** to restart it? Or can I let it run if further requests seem to work without a problem.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679330/catching-java-lang-outofmemoryerror

Answer (score 66, accepted):

It may work, but it is generally a bad idea.  There is no guarantee that your application will *succeed* in recovering, or that it will know if it has not succeeded.  For example:

- There really may be *not* enough memory to do the requested tasks, even after taking recovery steps like releasing block of reserved memory.  In this situation, your application may get stuck in a loop where it repeatedly appears to recover and then runs out of memory again.
- The OOME may be thrown on any thread.  If an application thread or library is not designed to cope with it, this might leave some long-lived data structure in an incomplete or inconsistent state.
- If threads die as a result of the OOME, the application may need to restart them as part of the OOME recovery.  At the very least, this makes the application more complicated.
- Suppose that a thread synchronizes with other threads using notify/wait or some higher level mechanism.  If that thread dies from an OOME, other threads may be left waiting for notifies (etc) that never come ... for example.  Designing for this could make the application significantly more complicated.

In summary, designing, implementing and testing an application to recover from OOMEs can be difficult, especially if the application (or the framework in which it runs, or any of the libraries it uses) is multi-threaded.  It is a better idea to treat OOME as a fatal error.

See also [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679330/catching-java-lang-outofmemoryerror/2679410#2679410) to a related question:

**EDIT** - in response to this followup question:

> In other words if an OOME is thrown in an application server (jboss/websphere/..) do I **have to** restart it?

No you don't **have to** restart.  But it is probably **wise** to, especially if you don't have a good / automated way of checking that the service is running correctly.

The JVM will recover just fine.  But the application server and the application itself may or may not recover, depending on how well they are designed to cope with this situation.  (My experience is that some app servers are *not* designed to cope with this, and that designing and implementing a complicated application to recover from OOMEs is hard, and testing it properly is even harder.)

**EDIT 2**

In response to this comment:

> *"other threads may be left waiting for notifies (etc) that never come"* Really? Wouldn't the killed thread unwind its stacks, releasing resources as it goes, including held locks?

Yes really!  Consider this:

Thread #1 runs this:

```
    synchronized(lock) {
         while (!someCondition) {
             lock.wait();
         }
    }
    // ...
```

Thread #2 runs this:

```
    synchronized(lock) {
         // do something
         lock.notify();
    }
```

If Thread #1 is waiting on the notify, and Thread #2 gets an OOME in the `// do something` section, then Thread #2 won't make the `notify()` call, and Thread #1 may get stuck forever waiting for a notification that won't ever occur.  Sure, Thread #2 is guaranteed to release the mutex on the `lock` object ... but that is not sufficient!

> If not the code ran by the thread is not exception safe, which is a more general problem.

"Exception safe" is not a term I've heard of (though I know what you mean).  Java programs are not normally designed to be resilient to unexpected exceptions.  Indeed, in a scenario like the above, it is likely to be somewhere between hard and impossible to make the application exception safe.

You'd need some mechanism whereby the failure of Thread #1 (due to the OOME) gets turned into an inter-thread communication failure notification to Thread #2.  Erlang does this ... but not Java.  The reason they can do this in Erlang is that Erlang processes communicate using strict CSP-like primitives; i.e. there is no sharing of data structures!

(Note that you could get the above problem for just about any *unexpected* exception ... not just `Error` exceptions.  There are certain kinds of Java code where attempting to recover from an *unexpected* exception is likely to end badly.)

Comment: "other threads may be left waiting for notifies (etc) that never come" Really? Wouldn't the killed thread unwind its stacks, releasing resources as it goes, including held locks? If not the code ran by the thread is not exception safe, which is a more general problem.

Comment: "The OOME may be thrown on any thread" and at any time, not just at a `new`. And that includes in locations that leave your program in an inconsistent state. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8728866/no-throw-virtualmachineerror-guarantees

Comment: For your edit 2 I would tend to say that `lock.wait();` is the problem, not the OOME itself, because the same behaviour could be caused by any runtime exception.

Comment: @SpaceTrucker - The difference is that other exceptions don't happen spontaneously.  They happen as a result of either a bug, or some condition that is predictable at some level.  OTOH, OOME and other Errors can happen spontaneously!  Where/when you run out of memory cannot be predicted ... in practice.  But it really doesn't matter who or what is "at fault".  The issue is that this kind of thing makes recovery from OOME's problematic.

Comment: I suppose one can carefully design and test an app to keep the state consistent after an  OOM. But if you use any third party libs then you never know. Check out this one: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HTTPCLIENT-2039

Comment: Yup.  That would be the kind of problem I alluded to when I said: *" ... especially if the application (or the framework in which it runs, **or any of the libraries it uses**) is multi-threaded."*.

Answer (score 4):

The JVM **will** run the GC when it's on edge of the `OutOfMemoryError`. If the GC didn't help at all, then the JVM will throw OOME.

You *can* however `catch` it and if necessary take an alternative path. Any allocations inside the `try` block will be GC'ed.

Since the OOME is "just" an `Error` which you could just `catch`, I would expect the different JVM implementations to behave the same. I can at least confirm from experience that the above is true for the Sun JVM.

**See also:**

- [Catching java.lang.OutOfMemoryError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679330/catching-java-lang-outofmemoryerror)
- [Is it possible to catch out of memory exception in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692230/is-it-possible-to-catch-out-of-memory-exception-in-java)

Comment: I would recommend catching it *high* on the stack. i.e. at the beginning of the task. That way, it can try to gc any data which would have been "in scope" at the time it ran out of memory.

Answer (score 4):

I'd say it depends partly on what caused the OutOfMemoryError.  If the JVM truly is running low on memory, it might be a good idea to restart it, and with more memory if possible (or a more efficient app).  However, I've seen a fair amount of OOMEs that were caused by allocating 2GB arrays and such.  In that case, if it's something like a J2EE web app, the effects of the error should be constrained to that particular app, and a JVM-wide restart wouldn't do any good.

Answer (score 3):

**Can** it recover?  Possibly.  Any well-written JVM is only going to throw an OOME after it's tried everything it can to reclaim enough memory to do what you tell it to do.  There's a very good chance that this means you can't recover.  But...

It depends on a lot of things.  For example if the garbage collector isn't a copying collector, the "out of memory" condition may actually be "no chunk big enough left to allocate".  The very act of unwinding the stack may have objects cleaned up in a later GC round that leave open chunks big enough for your purposes.  In that situation you may be able to restart.  It's probably worth at least retrying once as a result.  But...

You probably don't want to rely on this.  If you're getting an OOME with any regularity, you'd better look over your server and find out what's going on and why.  Maybe you have to clean up your code (you could be leaking or making too many temporary objects).  Maybe you have to raise your memory ceiling when invoking the JVM.  Treat the OOME, even if it's recoverable, as a sign that something bad has hit the fan somewhere in your code and act accordingly.  Maybe your server doesn't have to come down NOWNOWNOWNOWNOW, but you will have to fix something before you get into deeper trouble.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>Any sane JVM will throw an OutOfMemoryError only if there is nothing the Garbage collector can do. However, if you catch the OutOfMemoryError early enough on the stack frame it can be likely enough that the cause was itself became unreachable and was garbage collected (unless the problem is not in the current thread).</strike>

Generally frameworks that run other code, like application servers, attempting to continue in the face of an OME makes sense (as long as it can reasonably release the third-party code), but otherwise, in the general case, recovery should probably consist of bailing and telling the user why, rather than trying to go on as if nothing happened.

To answer your newly updated question: There is no reason to think you need to shut down the server if all is working well. My experience with JBoss is that as long as the OME didn't affect a deployment, things work fine. Sometimes JBoss runs out of permgen space if you do a lot of hot deployment. Then indeed the situation is hopeless and an immediate restart (which will have to be forced with a kill) is inevitable.

Of course each app server (and deployment scenario) will vary and it is really something learned from experience in each case.

Comment: *"Generally frameworks that run other code, like application servers, attempting to continue in the face of an OME makes sense"*.  I disagree, unless the framework is extremely robust, attempting to recover from an OOME can result in (for example) a catatonic server.  Been there, seen that!

Comment: @Stephen C, I shudder to think what calling System.exit(1) on any OME in JBoss would look like. Every time a user tired to read too much data, everyone goes down. I agree that it can lead to problems, but the most likely cause of an OME for an app server is user code doing too much, and as long as they catch it at a point where the user code allocations are no longer reachable, full-recovery is the most likely outcome and worth coding for, IMO.

Comment: @Yishai - a bad request (e.g. user tried to read too much data) should not be allowed to cause an OOME in the first place.  The correct fix is to make the request processing more defensive ... not to try to recover from OOMEs.

Comment: @Stephen C, the author of an application server doesn't have that option.

Comment: @Yishai - yes he/she does.  Just provide a way for ding-bat application developers / deployers to enable dodgy OOME recovery.

Comment: @Stephen C, in other words recover from it ;).

Comment: @Yishai - well *try to* recover from it.  As I said in my example, it is difficult to know if an OOME recovery has really worked.

Comment: @Yishai - a better answer would be to say that it is not the responsibility of the framework to cope with dingbat apps, developers, etc that cannot manage the apps demands on memory.

Answer (score 1):

You can increase your odds of recovering from this scenario although its not recommended that you try.  What you do is pre-allocate some fixed amount of memory on startup thats dedicated to doing your recovery work, and when you catch the OOM, null out that pre-allocated reference and you're *more* likely to have some memory to use in your recovery sequence.

I don't know about different JVM implementations.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot fully a JVM that had OutOfMemoryError. At least with the oracle JVM you can add `-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="cmd args;cmd args"` and take recovery actions, like kill the JVM or send the event somewhere.

Reference: https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html