# Java Memory Management with BufferedReader

Tags: java, memory-management, bufferedreader

Is it possible to add memory in JVM more than 5GB if the machine has installed memory 2GB only?

Because I got exception in thread, `java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`

I'm reading a text file which contains Strings that sized by 5gb, and I used BufferedReader to read lines.

Comment: Is it strictly necessary to load all of the file into memory?  Can you simply process portions of the file at a time?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3648454/what-happens-if-you-specify-max-heap-size-greater-than-available-ram might provide some pointers.

Comment: Not really, the data of the file is like 20 words per line. And I just need the 4 first word of that line.

Comment: Stream the data instead of hoisting them into memory

Comment: How? Should I use BufferedStream?

Answer (score 0):

Just process the data a line at a time, with `readLine()` and friends, maybe even a `Scanner.` It is never necessary to load a large file entirely into memory.

Comment: I'm storing the data line by line to ArrayList. But I think String variable can't hold more than 1m line.