# Elasticsearch Out of Memory Crash -- How to Delete Data?

Tags: elasticsearch

Well, I started piping data into ES until it ran itself out of memory and crashed. I run `free` and i see that all memory is entirely used up.

I want to delete some data out of it (old data) but i can't query against `localhost:9200`, it rejects the connection.

How to fix the fact that i can't delete out the old data?

Comment: Do you know what your ES_HEAP_SIZE is compared to the total memory on the machine? See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/heap-sizing.html and https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_limiting_memory_usage.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go hardcore about it, you can always delete anything in your data folder:

```
> rm $ES_HOME/data/<clustername>
```

Note: replace `<clustername>` with your real cluster name (the default is `elasticsearch`)

Answer (score 0):

Stop indexing. If it stabilizes itself after few minute then try deleting the data again. Restart the cluster.

If it's still stuck, stop the indexing and restart the cluster.

In any case, if the nodes went OOM they need to be restarted, as [the state the JVM is in is unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058198/can-the-jvm-recover-from-an-outofmemoryerror-without-a-restart).