# Post callback for JVM out of memory

Tags: java, callback, jvm, out-of-memory, heap-memory

In our java application, we need to send email in case the application goes out of memory and recovers from it by its own. To do so, we need a callback kind of thing that should be called once the JVM recovered from OOM. Is there such a callback in Java?

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058198/can-the-jvm-recover-from-an-outofmemoryerror-without-a-restart

Comment: What does "recovered" mean in this context?

Comment: @tgdavies 'recovered' means became responsive again. After recovery the JVM will function normally.

Comment: @MarcinWasiluk Not exactly duplicate.

Comment: As the answer to that question says, you are better off forcing your app to exit (and be restarted by your environment) than to let it keep running.

Answer (score 2):

Use `-XX:OnOutOfMemoryError=<command>` JVM option.

If you need more flexible error handling within the Java process itself, look at [`ResourceExhausted`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/specs/jvmti.html#ResourceExhausted) JVMTI callback.