# What is an OutOfMemoryError exception, and how can I produce it?

Tags: java, exception

For a homework exercise involving exception handling, I need to produce an OutOfMemoryError exception so I can write a try-catch and catch it:

> *"13.10 (OutOfMemoryError) Write a program that causes the JVM to throw an
>   OutOfMemoryError and catches and handles this error."*

I searched the Java API and couldn't find anything on OutOfMemoryError exceptions in the exception list. What is an OutOfMemoryError exception, and how can I produce one for my assignment?

Comment: What did you find out about OOMEs when you searched for them?

Comment: Hint: What's the name of the exception/error?

Comment: How to find Java API information on OutOfMemoryError: Go to the [API Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html), press Ctrl+F, type in OutOfMemoryError, and press enter.

Comment: Put an international crap-load of objects inside a collection - do this in a loop - and bingo - OOM.

Comment: Is that a British or metric crap-load?  Please clarify.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/1692230/859762

Comment: There's a number of ways to write a program that _throws_ the exception (doing something with an array would probably be your best bet), but I'm not sure about **catching** it...

Comment: @duffymo - I qualified the reference.

Comment: @X-Zero: catching is not the problem, but actually *handling* it might be.

Comment: @NiklasB. - Err, yes, that's what I meant.

Comment: Excellent, Chuck.  Thank you.  Insightful, as always.

Comment: @Mike: I heard some superior browsers support this very new and shiny feature called "incremental search", so simply pressing Ctrl+F and typing "OutOfM" might actually be enough!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is answered by the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OutOfMemoryError is thrown when the JVM can't allocate enough memory to complete the requested action.

To produce these just allocate a bunch of memory in a loop or something similar, but remember to keep your already allocated objects, preferably in a ArrayList or something, or else the garbage collector might reuse the space and free up some memory.

Something like

```
ArrayList<Object> list = new ArrayList<Object>();

try {
    while ( true )
        list.add( new Object() );
} catch ( OutOfMemoryError e ) {
    // And we are done...
}
```

You might want to replace Object with a class that takes up some considerable amount of space, or else this might take some time.

Reference:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html

Answer (score 5):

Much simpler (and guaranteed to work) than creating millions of objects:

```
public static void throwOomE() {
    throw new well, you can just search for the rest of the answer
}
```

Comment: I was just about to suggest this, +1

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way I can think of:

```
for (String x = "x";; x += x);
```

You might want to get a bit creative to crash it even faster.

Comment: Before you wrote "for(;;) {x = x + 1}" What does writing a for loop in that way mean? Also, thanks!"

Comment: @Zolani: `for(;;)` is an infinite loop.

Answer (score 3):

Much like I do with every java related question, the first thing I did was google:

```
java 6 <class-name>
```

In other words:

```
java 6 OutOfMemoryError
```

I got this informative link as the first result:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html

Comment: Let me yahoo that for you...

Answer (score 3):

My favorite way to do this is.

```
byte[] crasher = new byte[Integer.MAX_VALUE];
```

Answer (score 1):

An [OutOfMemoryError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html) is thrown by the VM when it runs out of memory for allocating new objects.  Thus you can cause this exception to hapen when you create too many objects.

To do so, start creating objects that will not be collected by the garbage collector (for example, link them to each other) in an infinite loop -- the VM will eventually run out of free memory for the next object to be allocated, throwing the exception.  When you catch it, be careful though as you won't be able to do much -- the VM does not have (much) memory left for any operations.

Answer (score 1):

[OutOfMemoryException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html) appears when your [heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_%28data_structure%29) contains no free space for new objects.
Also you should persist references for objects somewhere, otherwise [garbage colector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) takes care about they.

Binary crash (needed amount of bytes doubled on each iteration :)

```
String x = "1";
while (true){
    x = (x + x);
}
```

** read all references for better understanding