# Out of Memory Error during image compression

Tags: android, bitmap, compression, out-of-memory

I am currently following the tutorial from [this site](http://voidcanvas.com/whatsapp-like-image-compression-in-android/) to compress my images. It is working very well on some cellphones such as LG G3, Moto G and a few Samsung models. However, it causes Out-of-Memory error at this line for some phones such as Xiomi Mi4.

```
options.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];
```

The entire code is as follows -

```
public Bitmap compressImage(String imageLocation) {
    Bitmap scaledBitmap = null;

    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageLocation, options);

    int actualHeight = options.outHeight;
    int actualWidth = options.outWidth;
    float maxHeight = 700.0f;//816.0f;
    float maxWidth = 500.0f; //612.0f;
    float imgRatio = actualWidth / actualHeight;
    float maxRatio = maxWidth / maxHeight;

    if (actualHeight > maxHeight || actualWidth > maxWidth) {
        if (imgRatio < maxRatio) {
            imgRatio = maxHeight / actualHeight;
            actualWidth = (int) (imgRatio * actualWidth);
            actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
        } else if (imgRatio > maxRatio) {
            imgRatio = maxWidth / actualWidth;
            actualHeight = (int) (imgRatio * actualHeight);
            actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;
        } else {
            actualHeight = (int) maxHeight;
            actualWidth = (int) maxWidth;
        }
    }
    //options.inSampleSize = utils.calculateInSampleSize(options, actualWidth, actualHeight);
    options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    options.inDither = false;
    options.inPurgeable = true;
    options.inInputShareable = true;
    options.inTempStorage = new byte[16 * 1024];
    try {
        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imageLocation, options);
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(actualWidth, actualHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    } catch (OutOfMemoryError exception) {
        exception.printStackTrace();
    }

    float ratioX = actualWidth / (float) options.outWidth;
    float ratioY = actualHeight / (float) options.outHeight;
    float middleX = actualWidth / 2.0f;
    float middleY = actualHeight / 2.0f;

    Matrix scaleMatrix = new Matrix();
    scaleMatrix.setScale(ratioX, ratioY, middleX, middleY);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(scaledBitmap);
    canvas.setMatrix(scaleMatrix);
    canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, middleX - bmp.getWidth() / 2, middleY - bmp.getHeight() / 2, new Paint(Paint.FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG));


    ExifInterface exif;
    try {
        exif = new ExifInterface(imageLocation);

        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 0);
        Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        if (orientation == 6) {
            matrix.postRotate(90);
            Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
        } else if (orientation == 3) {
            matrix.postRotate(180);
            Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
        } else if (orientation == 8) {
            matrix.postRotate(270);
            Log.d("EXIF", "Exif: " + orientation);
        }
        scaledBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(scaledBitmap, 0, 0, scaledBitmap.getWidth(), scaledBitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return scaledBitmap;
}
```

Could someone please help me out/ give suggestions as to how I can improve this code so it takes less memory.

Comment: You could lower the quality

Comment: try to set options.inSampleSize = 16

Answer (score 1):

> You are dealing with large bitmaps and loading all of them at run
>   time. You have to deal very carefully with large bitmaps by loading
>   the size that you need not the whole bitmap at once and then do
>   scaling.

Please check below Link

1. [Is it possible to catch out of memory exception in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692230/is-it-possible-to-catch-out-of-memory-exception-in-java)

Comment: I am loading only one bitmap in that activity.

Comment: @VarunAgarwal Okay .Reduce image size

Comment: This code IS for reducing image size. Im taking an image from a camera (2-4mb depending on camera) and reducing it to something like 700kb. But it is not working on xiaomi m4 and some others. If i use an async task will that make a difference?

Comment: @VarunAgarwal You can try `async task` . But main problem is large size .I guess that's why have problem

Comment: True but now xiomi pictures ARE at that size. So i have to handle and compress them cause if I upload the image as is, it will take too long and it wont be efficient at all.

Comment: @VarunAgarwal Okay .set `android:largeHeap="true"` in your manifest

Answer (score 0):

You should set the sample size on the basis of required size. Try to set
options.inSampleSize dynamically. i.e

```
options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);
```

//Method

```
public static int calculateInSampleSize(BitmapFactory.Options options,
            int reqWidth, int reqHeight) {
        // Raw height and width of image
        final int height = options.outHeight;
        final int width = options.outWidth;
        int inSampleSize = 1;

        if (height > reqHeight || width > reqWidth) {

            final int halfHeight = height / 2;
            final int halfWidth = width / 2;

            // Calculate the largest inSampleSize value that is a power of 2 and
            // keeps both
            // height and width larger than the requested height and width.
            while ((halfHeight / inSampleSize) > reqHeight
                    && (halfWidth / inSampleSize) > reqWidth) {
                inSampleSize *= 2;
            }
        }

        return inSampleSize;
    }
```