# handling out of memory error in java gracefully

Tags: java, tomcat, out-of-memory

In our application , OOM happens and we end up restarting our tomcat servers.

This impacts the business continuity  . 
Is there any way to interrupt any thread which eats up the memory and throw error ( similar to transaction time out ) so that only that particular thread will be impacted

Not sure if this is even possible. 
Just wanted to check if any body has solution to address this issue

Comment: Or you could just fix your memory leaks.

Comment: Thanks Robby . While we are working on the same , if there can be a safety net  ,it would be useful.

Comment: Some insights here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692230/is-it-possible-to-catch-out-of-memory-exception-in-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your thread also takes much time, you can try the [Stuck Thread Detection Valve](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/valve.html#Stuck_Thread_Detection_Valve) in order to interrupt it. Please note there is no warranty and should be considered as experimental. Let us know if this helped in your case.