# In Java what happens when an object fails to be instantiated?

Tags: java, object, new-operator, instantiation, creation

I come from a c++ background and I find myself constantly doing this in java:

```
SomeClass sc=new SomeClass();

if(null!=sc)
{
    sc.doSomething();
}
```

What I want to know is what will be in the variable sc if the constructor fails for some reason (like maybe not enough memory).  I can'
t find a straight answer, and I am worried that I am just wasting my time because maybe if the new operator fails would the program just crash anyway?

Comment: In Java you don't have to use that *inverted* form of condition checking either, only boolean expressions are accepted in the `if(condition)`.

Comment: You come from a C++ background? You don't have to do this check in C++, either.

Comment: @Bakkal, even if it prevents only a pitfall with the boolean type in Java, many coding standard use this style as it leads to code that is easier to parse mentally when scanning code. (`if (0 == longMethodCallWithManyArguments()) {` versus `if (longMethodCallWithManyArguments() == 0) {`, the first style you don't need to read/parse the whole line to see what is meant.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The *Java Specification Language 3rd Edition* covers your question thoroughly:

> #### [12.5 Creation of New Class Instances](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/execution.html#12.5)
>
> Whenever a new class instance is created, memory space is allocated for it with room for all the instance variables declared in the class type and all the instance variables declared in each superclass of the class type, including all the instance variables that may be hidden. If there is not sufficient space available to allocate memory for the object, then creation of the class instance completes abruptly with an [`OutOfMemoryError`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html). Otherwise, all the instance variables in the new object, including those declared in superclasses, are initialized to their default values.
>
> Just before a reference to the newly created object is returned as the result, the indicated constructor is processed to initialize the new object using the following procedure: [...]

So it's simply not possible for a `new` expression to return `null`. Whatever is returned, if the execution completes normally, will always be a valid `instanceof` whatever class was instantiated.

---

#### Handling exceptions

Generally speaking, possible exceptions are usually handled with a `try-catch` block:

```
String someString = askFromUser();
try {
   int num = Integer.parseInt(someString);
   doSomethingWith(num);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
   complainAboutIt();
}
```

In your case, you may consider putting `new SomeClass()` in a `try` block with a corresponding `catch (OutOfMemoryError e)`, but this is highly atypical. Unless you plan to do something meaningful when this happens, in most typical scenarios it's best to not `catch` any [`Error`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html) that may occur during your program execution.

From the documentation:

> An `Error` is a subclass of `Throwable` that indicates serious problems that a reasonable application should not `try` to `catch`. Most such errors are abnormal conditions.
>
> A method is not required to declare in its `throws` clause any subclasses of `Error` that might be thrown during the execution of the method but not caught, since these errors are abnormal conditions that should never occur.

#### Related questions

- [Catching java.lang.OutOfMemoryError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679330/catching-java-lang-outofmemoryerror)
- [When to catch java.lang.Error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/352780/when-to-catch-java-lang-error)
- [Is it possible to catch out of memory exception in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692230/is-it-possible-to-catch-out-of-memory-exception-in-java)
- [Can the JVM recover from an OutOfMemoryError without a restart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058198/can-the-jvm-recover-from-an-outofmemoryerror-without-a-restart)
- [How to handle OutOfMemoryError in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511013/how-to-handle-outofmemoryerror-in-java)

#### See also

- [Java Tutorials/Exceptions](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html)

Comment: Just to be clear, you're saying is that a class will always be initialized and if not the program will crash? So it is safe to assume that during the running of a program all classes that are initialized and then instantiated - with out throwing an Error/Exception - will always have their constructors called and be usable?

Answer (score 7):

If the constructor failed, then it would throw an exception or an error and you wouldn't get any further in the program. Specifically, if it ran out of memory, you would get an `OutOfMemoryError`.

Comment: `OutOfMemoryError`, if memory serves. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

```
SomeClass sc=new SomeClass();

if(null!=sc) { sc.doSomething(); }
```

An object reference is never `null` after creating an object, so the null check is unnecessary because the condition will always be true.

If, for example, there is not enough memory at the point in the constructor, an `OutOfMemoryError` will be thrown and the constructor will not return normally.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are wasting your time :-).  sc is guaranteed to be non-null after the constructor is called.  If the constructor failed an exception would be thrown and the following code would never be run.  Hence the following is safe in Java:

```
SomeClass sc = new SomeClass();
sc.doSomething();
```

without throwing a NullPointerException.

Comment: To pick nits, `NullPointerException` can result from the execution of `doSomething()` itself, e.g. if it's `doSomethingStupid()`.

Answer (score 1):

That `if` check is not needed, and some IDEs will even complain that it is unnecessary as it always evaluates to `true`. The only reason that `new` would fail is if the constructor threw an exception, and in that case your `if` check will be bypassed anyways.

Answer (score 0):

An [OutOfMemoryError](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html) is thrown which will usually crash the virtual machine. 
(Could be catched as Throwable)

You might find [Prevent and Recover from Java OutOfMemory Error](http://www.taranfx.com/prevent-and-recover-from-java-outofmemory-error) useful.